# Box falls extremely slow? (~1 pixel per second)

Tags: c++, physics, box2d

As the title says I have a problem where my box2d bodies falls extremely slow.

Around 1 pixel per second.

---

My world is stepped like this `world.Step(1 / 60.0f, 8, 3);`, each frame.

The way I update my `sf::RectangleShape` to match the `b2Body` position is like this :

*(Called every frame)*

```
sfmlShape.setPosition(getBody()->GetPosition().x / b2Meter, getBody()->GetPosition().y / b2Meter);
```

---

Not sure what else is needed to fix this problem, so here's some other stuff that might be the problem :

> **b2Body values :**
>
> `friction = 1.0f`
>
> `density = 0.3f`
>
> `body type = dynamic`

---

The `b2PolygonShape` is set up like this : `boxShape.SetAsBox(size.x / 2.0f, size.y / 2.0f);`

And the size of the actual `sf::RectangleShape` is set up like this :

```
sfmlShape.setSize(sf::Vector2f(size.x, size.y));
```

---

And lastly : `b2Meter` is a macro :

```
#define b2Meter 30.0f
```

Comment: Did you do any debbugging or add prints to see if position change is right? That could tell you if it is a physics or rendering problem

Comment: @Steven Check the video console window, that prints the body positions.

Comment: Sorry video not working ob my phone

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is your update loop - you are updating a 1/60th of a second, but as fast as you can. The is interrupted by the event handler, which will make it jittery.

Somehow you need to change your loop to only update if 1/60th of a second has passed, or by actually passing the real delta time in. I believe bullet would prefer a fixed update, but you actually need that update to be a bit more realistic, and not full tilt.

Where is there a gate to how fast the outer while loop runs in the following code? You are updating physics 1/60th of a second but at what rate? how often? how fast? Does display always take the same amount of tim? No - same as the event handling, so the movement of the physics objects via step(1/60) is inconsistent.

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event e;
    while (window.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if (e.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (e.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)
                box.getBody()->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(0, -100000), b2Vec2(0, -10000));
        }
    }

    // Logic
    world.Step(1.0f / 60.0f, 8, 3);
    // Update all entities in the game
    box.update(window.isOpen());
    // Drawing
    window.clear();
    window.draw(*box.getSfShape());
    window.setView(view);
    window.display();
}
```

Instead you need some kind of loop like this:

```
time_step_accumulator = 0;
previous_time = get_current_time();
while ( true )
{
   while ( pollEvents )
   {
      // handle events
   }

   current_time = get_current_time();
   delta_time = current_time - previous_time;
   previous_time = current_time; // for next frame

   time_step_accumulator += delta_time;

   while ( time_step_accumulator > 1/60th )
   {
      step_physics( 1/60th):
      time_step_accumulator -= 1/60th;
   }

   display();

}
```

This will only do steps when enough time has passed to perform them, and only as many as are needed (in the case of a long lag).

Comment: I think I understand, I will try it as soon as I can :)

Comment: Nope I don't understand. lol. I can't see anyone else doing this in their games.. They just do it like I do and get a perfect result :/

Comment: In our games we do *something* to cope with the fact that rendering & event handling don't always take the same time - do you understand the issue I am trying to express - that you are going to update the physics at an unreliable rate, so it will fall, but jerkily.

Comment: Yes, but when other people do it, it looks perfect. Even though they do it the same way as I do. o.o